# Result of multiple lines in to one separed by commas

Tags: powershell

I try to put some result of multiple lines in to one separed  by commas.

With the following command I get this result:

```
((Get-BrokerSession -SessionState Disconnected |Select-Object UserName,MachineName | ft -hidetableheaders | Out-String | ForEach-Object { $_.Trim() }))

host1
user@host1
```

I try to put this result in only unique one line separated by commas by adding:

```
-join ', '
```

But the result is the same:

```
((Get-BrokerSession -SessionState Disconnected |Select-Object UserName,MachineName | ft -hidetableheaders | Out-String | ForEach-Object { $_.Trim() })) -join ', '

host1
user@host1
```

What's wrong in that case?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Drop the `ft | Out-String` stuff and just do ``Get-BrokerSession -SessionState Disconnected | ForEach-Object {"{0}`r`n{1}" -f $_.MachineName, $_.UserName}``

Comment: same result. I see multiple lines

Comment: Ah, didn;t catch that. Then do ``Get-BrokerSession -SessionState Disconnected | ForEach-Object {"{0},{1}" -f $_.MachineName, $_.UserName}``

Comment: Now I see the two columns in one line separated by commas but need to add all this new lines to only one line.

Comment: I do it!: (Get-BrokerSession -SessionState Disconnected | ForEach-Object {"{0},{1}" -f $_.MachineName, $_.UserName}) -join ', '

Answer (score 1):

When you pipe to `Format-Table` you are creating a table object. Piping that to `Out-String` will create a single string from your formatted table. So, running `-join ','` is actually joining one string with nothing because it's a single string.

Working with custom object types and doing conversions to custom outputs can be a little tricky, because the object can hold complex data where calling `out-string` doesn't get you what you'd expect.

Here's one way to get what you're looking for:

```
(Get-BrokerSession -SessionState Disconnected |           # Get the original objects
    Select-Object UserName, MachineName |                 # Select just the fields you want to keep 
    Foreach-Object {                                      # Iterate over each nested object and...
        $_.psobject.Members |                             
        Where-Object MemberType -like 'noteproperty' |    # Get only the members that are the note properties you selected
        Foreach-Object {                                  # Iterate over each note property and...
            $_.Value.toString()                           # Convert just the value of the property to a string
        }
    }) -join ','                                          # The result is an array which you can perform -join on
```

I don't know your particular use case but if possible I would recommend standardized formats like .csv, .xml, or .json. If you can manage to use those instead the previous block turns into simply:

```
Get-BrokerSession -SessionState Disconnected | 
    Select-Object UserName, MachineName | 
    ConvertTo-CSV
```